# Как собрать .apk и .ipo из react native по средством сервиса

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Имеется ресурс expo.io очень удобный, практический готовый каркас,  но я не понял возможном там собрать .apk или .ipo если да то как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

использовать expo-cli и команды

```
build:ios|bi [options] [project-dir]            Build a standalone IPA for your project, signed and ready for submission to the Apple App Store.
build:android|ba [options] [project-dir]        Build a standalone APK for your project, signed and ready for submission to the Google Play Store.
build:status|bs [options] [project-dir]         Gets the status of a current (or most recently finished) build for your project.
```

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/workflow/expo-cli